# MySQL query including records with no corresponding records in related table

Tags: mysql

Having a little difficulty getting my head around this one in MySQL. I'm trying to return the results from a table of resources and booking dates. So my end result will be something like this

```
              |Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|
Resource Name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11| 12| 13|
--------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
Resource1     |   |   | X | X | X |   | X | X | X |   |   | X |   |
Resource2     |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
Resource3     |   | X | X | X | X | X |   |   | X | X | X |   |   |
Resource4     |   |   |   | X |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
Resource5     |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | X |   |   |   |   |
```

My issue occurs with Resource2 in the table above as it has NO bookings.

I have two tables, one contains my resources, the other my bookings. My bookings table includes a unique ID of my resource:

bookings: bookings.id, bookings.first_date, bookings.last_date, bookings.resource_id

resources: resources.id, resource.name

A resource can have many bookings, conversely a booking can in this instance, only have a single resource.

My front end can cope with date ranges so I do not need to return a record for each day that a resource is booked, only the date range.

It is easy to get a list of resources where a booking exists using:

```
SELECT resources.name, bookings.id, bookings.first_date, bookings.last_date, bookings.property_id FROM resources
LEFT JOIN bookings ON (bookings.resource_id = resources.id)
WHERE bookings.first_date  > NOW()
ORDER BY resources.name
```

but I am finding it more challenging to get a list of all the resources and when they are booked as a single result.

What is an efficient way to get a result which includes any resource without any bookings as per my sample table above.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It is hard to understand where is your problem without seeing your current query. Would you share it with us?

Comment: Hi ruuter, hope that edit helps. I was trying not to influence the answers that people came back with.

Comment: I believe I have a working solution to this problem. It involves a SELECT DISTINCT, LEFT JOIN and an AND in the JOIN statement.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a working solution.

```
SELECT DISTINCT resources.name, bookings.id, bookings.first_date, bookings.last_date, bookings.property_id 
FROM resources
LEFT JOIN bookings ON bookings.resource_id = resources.id AND bookings.first_date  > NOW()
ORDER BY resource.name
```